# Excel mobile aggregate conversion of a code

Tags: microsoft-excel

I use this code 
=INDEX(B:B,SMALL(IF(A2:A1000<1, ROW(A2:A1000)),RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTIF(A2:A1000,"<1")))) to pick a random cell from the b column that doesnt have 100% set in the a column. This works in excel on a laptop if you press ctrl+shift+enter right after pasting it. I can't do the same on a tablet because ctrl is missing.

Edit: as pointed out below, you apparently cannot use formulas on excel mobile but someone told me that maybe it could be converted to an "aggregate"? How? Thanks

Comment: Are there duplicates in column A (other than 100%)?

Comment: This looks like it works if there aren't any duplicates: `=INDEX(B2:B100,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,(--(A2:A100<1)*A2:A100),RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTIF(A2:A100,"<1"))),A2:A100,0))` If there are duplicates I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Just for zero percents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but you need to add another column. In column C, add this formula and autofill down:

```
=ROW()
```

Then use this formula:

```
=INDEX(B2:B1000,MATCH(AGGREGATE(14,6,(--(A2:A1000<1)*C2:C1000),RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNTIF(A2:A1000,"<1"))),C2:C1000,0))
```

The key change is this bit:

```
(--(A2:A1000<1)*C2:C1000)
```

Since column C contains the row number, this is equivalent to `IF(A2:A1000<1, ROW(A2:A1000))`, but doesn't have to be array-entered.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have Excel's mobile version on your tablet, unfortunately that doesn't support array formulas (and also many other functions).

See official information here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Office-Mobile-for-Windows-Phone-011b83c4-0d5f-4ea8-bbbe-2ed0d76dc69c?omkt=en-0

Comment: I do have excel mobile. Thanks for the link, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

This is just a workaround: upload your worksheet on Google Docs. You can refresh formulas by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: I don't have ctrl on the tablet, which is the whole problem

Comment: I see. In any case, you have those formulas on Google, you have to find out how to "roll dice" on your mobile... maybe going into formula edit mode and confirming again?

Comment: On my phone, tapping back and re-opening updates the sheet, picking a random value again.

Comment: I do have a calculate button which does the same thing. It just does not like functions on mobile for some reason. Found out that it could be converted to an "aggregate" though. I edited the question.

Comment: I guess you're still talking about Excel. `Aggregate` might be painful to convert to, not even sure if that's possible in this case. Try reading documentation and publish your experience please